# Event Viewer from Recovery Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I've got a 2008 Server machine that's doing a rolling reboot, even from safe mode. I can get into the recovery console prompt. From there can I somehow view what's in the event viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would boot off of a [BARTPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) CD and then open the event viewer files (in %SystemRoot%\System32\Config) from its event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to comment on an existing post, but the post about BARTPE CD is either not possible with Windows 7 or not a very easy thing to do. http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=23931 has some instructions on this